# SQLAlchemy "no module sasl"

Tags: python, hive, sqlalchemy, sasl

I want to return a query by establishing a hive connection with SQLalchemy. But I am getting "no module sasl" error with this code. Normally, I could get rid of this error with a solution such as auth = "NOSASL" in other connection modules, but here create_engine does not support such a function.

```
engine = create_engine("hive:///localhost:4444")

base = declarative_base()

class nat_par_final(base):
    __tablename__ = "Sample"
    customer_id = Column(String)



factory = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = factory()

for instance in session.query(sample):
    print(instance.customer_id)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "sasl"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('hive://localhost:10000/?auth=NOSASL')
data= engine.execute('select * from country.employees')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).